# Can Pig be used to LOAD from Parquet table in HDFS with partition, and add partitions as columns?

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs, database-partitioning, parquet

I have an Impala partitioned table, store as Parquet. Can I use Pig to load data from this table, and add partitions as columns?

The Parquet table is defined as:

```
create table test.test_pig (
    name: chararray,
    id bigint
)
partitioned by (gender chararray, age int)
stored as parquet;
```

And the Pig script is like:

```
A = LOAD '/test/test_pig' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader AS (name: bytearray, id: long);
```

However, `gender` and `age` are missing when `DUMP A`. Only `name` and `id` are displayed.

I have tried with:

```
A = LOAD '/test/test_pig' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader AS (name: bytearray, id: long, gender: chararray, age: int);
```

But I would receive error like:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1031: Incompatable
>   schema: left is "name:bytearray,id:long,gender:bytearray,age:int",
>   right is "name:bytearray,id:long"

Hope to get some advice here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test with the  org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader library.

Normally, Pig supports read from/write into partitioned tables;

**read:**

> This load statement will load all partitions of the specified table.
>   /* myscript.pig */
>   A = LOAD 'tablename' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
>   ...
>   ...
>   If only some partitions of the specified table are needed, include a partition filter statement immediately following the load statement in the data flow. (In the script, however, a filter statement might not immediately follow its load statement.) The filter statement can include conditions on partition as well as non-partition columns.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore#HCatalogLoadStore-RunningPigwithHCatalog

**write**

> HCatOutputFormat will trigger on dynamic partitioning usage if necessary (if a key value is not specified) and will inspect the data to write it out appropriately.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+DynamicPartitions

However, I think this hasn't been yet properly tested with parquet files (at least not by the Cloudera guys) :

> Parquet has not been tested with HCatalog. Without HCatalog, Pig cannot correctly read dynamically partitioned tables; that is true for all file formats.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html